# forecast package versions giving different result on loess time series

Tags: r, stl, version, forecasting

I am using forecast package on R Studio with R version 3.3.2. I am forecasting a time series with loess method (stl). Issue is when I run the same code on R version 3.4.1 the results are very different from what I got on version 3.3.2. Below is the section of code where I am facing issue.

```
wcfit <- stl(wcts, t.window=4, s.window="periodic", robust=TRUE)

fcast <- forecast(wcfit,h=8, method="naive")
```

fcast values are different in both the cases. Please help

Below are the sample outputs of the same time series in both the cases:

R3.3.2

```
        Point Forecast       Lo 80    Hi 80      Lo 95    Hi 95

2017 Q1       3528.904   927.43592 6130.372  -449.6980 7507.506
2017 Q2       2619.054    17.58643 5220.522 -1359.5475 6597.656
2017 Q3       3393.551   792.08334 5995.019  -585.0506 7372.153
2017 Q4        647.000 -1954.46786 3248.468 -3331.6018 4625.602
2018 Q1       3528.904  -150.12735 7207.935 -2097.6888 9155.496
2018 Q2       2619.054 -1059.97684 6298.085 -3007.5383 8245.647
2018 Q3       3393.551  -285.47993 7072.582 -2233.0414 9020.144
2018 Q4        647.000 -3032.03113 4326.031 -4979.5926 6273.593
```

R3.4.1

```
        Point Forecast      Lo 80     Hi 80      Lo 95     Hi 95

2017 Q1       3528.904   927.4359  6130.372   -449.698  7507.506
2017 Q2       2619.054 -1059.9768  6298.085  -3007.538  8245.647
2017 Q3       3393.551 -1112.3233  7899.426  -3497.589 10284.692
2017 Q4        647.000 -4555.9357  5849.936  -7310.204  8604.204
2018 Q1       3528.904 -2288.1552  9345.963  -5367.520 12425.328
2018 Q2       2619.054 -3753.2145  8991.323  -7126.490 12364.598
2018 Q3       3393.551 -3489.2858 10276.388  -7132.840 13919.942
2018 Q4        647.000 -6711.0623  8005.062 -10606.185 11900.185
```

I have also realised that version R3.2.1 gives the same result as 3.4.1

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some specifics on the differences you're seeing between the two versions?

Comment: Do you have reproducible example?

Comment: In both the versions the point forecasts are same but the confidence intervals are wider in case of R3.4.1.

Comment: The version of R is probably irrelevant. What matters is the version of the forecast package. What versions are you using?

Comment: Hi Rob, in case of R3.3.2, forecast package version is 7.3 while in R3.4.1 it is 8.2

Comment: It's possible due to this bug fix: https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/commit/a7a846bd4489f6fd5aec01275284bd8134f0d877#diff-3e90ce00b16b414278ec62eee2621324